# STRIPE - Subscription plan only for 5 month - using Laravel Cashier (stripe)

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

- Cashier Version: "^12.13"
- Laravel Version: "^8.0"
- PHP Version: "^7.3"

Hi There!,

I have been wrote a code for create and active subscription plan using "Laravel cashier (stripe)" and It's working good but I want to add some conditions like "I want to active this plan only for 5 month".

In the stripe documentation we can set "ITERATION" during create subscription plan, means If I want to create Subscription plan only for 5 month so I need to set "iteration : 5" (https://prnt.sc/12wnbez).

So here, in Laravel cashier how can I manage it?

Can you please give me any suggestion for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Subscription Schedules in Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#installment-plans), but I'm not sure if Cashier supports those.

Comment: Thank you for replying me.

Let me try with this. Do you have any GitHub link for integrate in Laravel?

Comment: I do not, no.  Sorry.